# Count all the four-letter words

Tags: c

I have made this simple program

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char s1[] = "aaaa bbb cccc";
    int pos = 0, i, cont = 0;

    for (i = 0; s1[i] != '\0'; i += pos + 1)
        if (((pos = strcspn( s1 + i, " " )) == 4 && s1[i - 1] == ' '))
            cont++;

    printf("Quantity: %d\n", cont);

    return 0;
}
```

This program account all the four-letter words, the problem is in that no account the first word of the string the which has four letters, I have no idea how I can get it to work.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: does it work if the first word is not a four-letter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program does not count the first word because it requires that the character immediately *before* the word is space:

```
s1[i - 1] == ' '
```

This is not correct when `i` is zero (and it is also undefined behavior). Note that this condition can be dropped altogether, because there is always a space at position `pos` returned from `strcspn`, and you always continue at a position `pos+1`.